# evil: Make `%s/x/y/gc` use case insensitive matching but do case sensitive replaces

Tags: evil, regular-expressions, vim-emulation, query-replace-regexp

How do I make `%s/x/y/gc` use case insensitive matching but do case sensitive replaces?

In emacs terms, I want `case-fold-search` but not `case-replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code of `evil-ex-substitute` (using `C-h f`), the value for `case-replace` is set to the value of `case-fold-search` in the `let*` form.

So it looks like there is no configuration option provided for this by default. But of course you can just replace the `case-fold-search` with `(not case-fold-search)` after the `case-replace` in that `let*` and (re)evaluate the `evil-ex-substitute` function definition.

NOTE how the value of `case-fold-search` is set via `evil-ex-pattern-ignore-case`. This a.o. means that you can use vim style patterns to set the value for `case-fold-search` (using `\c/\C` as explained e.g. [in this SE-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287449/6837095)).

Comment: I opened an FR: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/1513